# How to parse String into Gregorian Calendar?

Tags: android

I converted Gregorian Calendar to String by using `toString()` method to upload my DataBase. ( Because My Database doesn't apply Calendar type ) 
Here Example.

```
String Time = 
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=GMT,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=false,startYear=0,startMode=0,startMonth=0,startDay=0,startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=0,endMonth=0,endDay=0,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=2,WEEK_OF_YEAR=12,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=22,DAY_OF_YEAR=81,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

How do I parse it to Calendar type?
Much appreciate if you guys could help.

Comment: Instead of storing calendar as a string you can try storing the long value which you can get from `timeInMillis()`. This value will be easier to convert back to a calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can save `GregorianCalendar`'s millis in the database which will be of a `long` type. Here is how you do it:

```
 long millis = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

and when you want the `GregorianCalendar` instance in your app just get the millis from the database and add those millis to `GregorianCalendar` instance like this :

```
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
gregorianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
```

Comment: Thanks fro helping me. Your answer is what I wanted to.
I'll try,

Comment: @whittakerBen Did it work?

Comment: Absolutely, you've made my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat like this.

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,23); (etc)
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String time = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't save the string representation of Calendar. Save the timestamp as Long.

Here an example:

```
Calendar cal1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
long timeStamp = cal1.getTimeInMillis();

Calendar cal2 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal2.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
```